# How do I return only fields that are needed in Mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

How do I perform a query that doesn't return the entire document, but only fields that I have specified?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

From the horse's mouth:

```
# Return only the first and last names of each person.
  Person.only(:first_name, :last_name)
```

Source: http://mongoid.org/docs/querying/criteria.html#only

Answer (score 5):

you can also use `pluck`

```
Person.all.pluck(:first_name, :last_name, :id)
```

http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/Mongoid%2FContextual%2FMongo%3Apluck

Comment: Could you like to the documentation for `#pluck`

Comment: This doesn't work with mongoid with multiple fields to pluck.

Comment: It does work with multiple fields, at least with mongoid 6.2.1. It returns a 2d array.